# How can I get my old XBOX Live gamertag back?

Tags: xbox-network

My previous gamertag was "PlanetOrtalon86" and I changed it to "PlanetO86". I want to change it back, but I'm getting an error message saying something like:

> Maximum Length: 12 Characters

How do I change it back to the old gamertag?

Comment: +1, this question has gone from being a confusing lump of text to a clear question which describes what you want.

Answer (score 2):

How gamertags work has changed a bit over the years, but currently the basic restrictions are:

> Gamertags can be up to 12 characters long, including spaces. They can’t start with a number.

Previously, 16 characters were supported, but this changed to support suffixing:

> We require at least 3 characters to auto-assign you a suffix and make sure that everybody has an equal chance to have a name they can be proud of. Many older games allowed 16 characters for displaying gamertags. We reserve three of those characters for the suffix and one for the # symbol, leaving 12 characters for gamertags.

Unfortunately, there's no way to get your old gamertag back if it doesn't meet the current requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to fire up an Xbox 360 console and change your gamertag from there. However you may end up with an issue where you technically have 2 gamertags. Like, some games may show your new (longer) gamertag but in the Xbox Guide it will show your old (shorter) gamertag.

I've met someone like that a while ago. From the in-game leaderboard I opened his profile and the profile that opened had a different gamertag.